# how to remove multiple characters from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to understand how to make my code more concise. I have the following statement which works fine:

```
cleaned = dc_listings['price'].str.replace(',', '').str.replace('$', '')
```

However, when I try using a regex, as in the below, it does not work:

```
cleaned = dc_listings['price'].str.replace(',|$', '')
```

The cleaned variable still contains some '$' entries... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need escape `$` by `\`, because special `regex character` - end of string:

```
dc_listings = pd.DataFrame({'price':[',ll','j$,']})
cleaned = dc_listings['price'].str.replace(',|\$', '')
print (cleaned)
0    ll
1     j
Name: price, dtype: object
```